Как вызвать отдельные шаблоны на разных устройствах get_template_part
Здраствуйте.
Подскажите возможно вызывать разные шаблоны на разных устройствах через get_template_part?
Скажем на ПК вызывается:
<?php get_template_part('loop1'); ?>

А на мобильных устройствах:
<?php get_template_part('loop2'); ?>


Технически можно, есть функция wp_is_mobile() но я бы наверное не рекомендовал ей пользоваться, да и не серверная это задача, заниматься респонсивом и всем остальным, потому подключайте оба темплейт парта, а видимость тех или иных элементов делайте посредством CSS стилей и media queries.

Если это придумано ради адаптива, то это  в корне неверный подход. Так стоит делать только для реализации функционала, зависимого от устройства. Но вряд ли в этом случае нужно использовать разные template_part.

Вы можете вызывать разные шаблоны на разных устройствах, используя проверку user agent.
Пример:
<?php
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if (strpos($useragent, 'Mobile') !== false || strpos($useragent, 'Android') !== false || strpos($useragent, 'Silk/') !== false) {
    // Мобильное устройство
    get_template_part('loop2');
} else {
    // ПК
    get_template_part('loop1');
}
?>

Данный вариант будет работать в большинстве случаев.
Так-же как подметил @Simon в комментарии выше, если различия только в вёрстке страниц, а не в кардинальных различиях предоставляемой информации, то данный функционал необходимо делегировать на frontend часть проекта (css, js).

Проверила, работает, Cпасибо вам за помощь!
